# debug segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I need help debugging the following block of code. This block of code gives me a segmentation fault error only when i attempt to assign an appropriate(char) value to squares[ i ][ j ]. How can I fix this?

```
for(int i=0;i<sides;i++){
    for(int j=0;i<sides;j++){
        squares[i][j] = '';
    }
}
```

I declared the array squares[][] with the following code before the nested for loop:

```
char **squares = new(nothrow) char*[sides-1];
for(int i=0; i < sides-1; i++){
    squares[i] = new char[sides-1];
}
```

Comment: the inner loop has a `i<sides` instead of `j<sides`

Comment: you only created sides-1 arrays, but you try to access "sides" number of them in your loop(change the i<sides to i<sides-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *much* better way to declare an empty string array would be to use `String[]` Don't forget you're in C++.
And in your case, since it looks like you're wanting to do a square array, you could use a `std::array` if the sizes are known or a `std::vector` for unknown sizes. 
Now for the strict answer, use j in your second loop instead of i.

```
for(int i=0;i<sides - 1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<sides - 1;j++){
        squares[i][j] = '';
    }
}
```

I'm **strongly** encouraging you to try to look at your problem with Strings instead of re-inventing the wheel.
(Thanks to NathanOliver &  jsantander for the help)

Comment: Don't forget what @Creis said: the loop limits are wrong too.

Comment: @jsantander yeah, thanks for the reminder, i'm changing that right now

Comment: It would even be better to use a `std::array` if the sizes are known or a `std::vector` for unknown sizes.

Comment: @NathanOliver Updating my answer with that, thanks for your output nathan

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration,try to change the i < sides - 1 to i < sides

```
char **squares = new(nothrow) char*[sides-1];
for(int i=0; i < sides; i++){
    squares[i] = new char[sides-1];
}
```